# Can not install DBD-mysql in Win8.1

Tags: mysql, perl, perl-module, dbd

I install DBD-mysql in win8 environment, but it shows error as follows.

I use ActivePerl 5.10, mysql 5.5.  Can anyone help me?

In fact, I don't want to install from source. But it is not easy to find a ppm package.

If some system path not added, then it would be easy to handle.   But this error showed some windows library needed, then I really don't know how to set and where to set this, because this means I should change the source code of DBD-mysql? But each time I use the '  perl -MCPAN -e "install DBD::mysql"  ' command to install, it downloads a new DBD-mysql package, so even I modified the code locally, it would be of no use.

```
   Creating library blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.lib and object blib\arch\auto
\DBD\mysql\mysql.exp
mysqlclient.lib(handshake_client.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbo
l __imp__InitializeSecurityContextW@48 referenced in function "public: virtual c
lass Blob __thiscall Handshake_client::process_data(class Blob const &)" (?proce
ss_data@Handshake_client@@UAE?AVBlob@@ABV2@@Z)
mysqlclient.lib(handshake.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Comp
leteAuthToken@8 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall Handshake::pr
ocess_result(int)" (?process_result@Handshake@@IAE_NH@Z)
mysqlclient.lib(handshake.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Free
ContextBuffer@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Security_buffer:
:free(void)" (?free@Security_buffer@@QAEXXZ)
mysqlclient.lib(handshake.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Acqu
ireCredentialsHandleA@36 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Handshake::H
andshake(char const *,enum Handshake::side_t)" (??0Handshake@@QAE@PBDW4side_t@0@
@Z)
mysqlclient.lib(handshake.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__DeleteSecurityContext@4 referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Han
dshake::~Handshake(void)" (??1Handshake@@UAE@XZ)
mysqlclient.lib(handshake.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__FreeCredentialsHandle@4 referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Han
dshake::~Handshake(void)" (??1Handshake@@UAE@XZ)
mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetUser
NameExW@12 referenced in function "public: __thiscall UPN::UPN(void)" (??0UPN@@Q
AE@XZ)
blib\arch\auto\DBD\mysql\mysql.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.028.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
```

Answer (score 0):

At last, I solve it.  Environment must first be noted: Win8.1 + ActivePerl 5.16 + Mysql 5.5.

1) Open the windows command line, run:

```
set path=%path%;D:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
```

2) Config mysql database, add a new user with UserName='ODBC', and password setted as NULL.

3) cd into:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib
```

and create a subdir as “opt”;

4) Install strawberry perl, copy libmysql.a and libmysql_.dll to

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\opt;
```

5) Uninstall strawberry;

6) set path=%path%;D:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\opt

7) run command in the same command line console:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install DBD::mysql"
```

Everything is ok now.